# What would be the best way to extract square meters from a string that also mentions the amount of bedrooms?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, extract, text-extraction

I'm trying to extract:

```
<div class="xl-surface-ch"> 
                            &nbsp;84 m²  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2 bed.  
                        </div>
```

from [link](https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/apartment/for-sale/leuven/3000) the problem is, I only need the "84" in this string (they sometimes go over 2 or 3 digits as well).

Added difficulty is that sometimes the square meters are not mentioned, which looks like this:

```
<div class="xl-surface-ch"> 
                             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2 bed.  
                        </div>
```

and in that case I'd need to return a 0

My best attempt is:

```
    sqm = []
for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'xl-surface-ch'}):
    item = item.contents[0].strip()[0:4]
    item_clean = re.findall("[0-9]{2,4}", item)
    sqm.append(item_clean)

print(sqm)
```

But this doesn't seem to work and won't be at all what I need for the end result as stated above.
Here's the result I'm getting with my code:

```
[['84'], ['70'], ['80'], ['32'], ['149'], ['22'], ['75'], ['30'], ['23'], ['104'], [], ['95'], ['129'], ['26'], ['55'], ['26'], ['25'], ['28'], ['33'], ['210'], ['37'], ['69'], ['36'], ['19'], ['119'], ['20'], ['20'], ['129'], ['154'], ['25']]
```

Would be really interested in what kinds of solution you guys cook up because I honestly think there isn't really a solution, especially since you sometimes have buildings without the sqm... maybe with an if statement? I'm going to try that right now anyhow.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should include more possible inputs with their expected outputs, if the html parsing part works then it'd help to reduce your [mcve] down to just the regex part.

Comment: Have you checked my edit? I managed to get out only the first 2-4 numbers it finds. Which should be correct. Now I'm trying to unpack and add them to a column in excel but I can't seem to unpack & export it for some reason...

Comment: I think that I've been working on same site but for price

Comment: Hi Ahmed! Nice to find you here again. That's right, I'm now trying to figure out this. I've gotten it to the point that I managed to get out the numbers but they're in a list inside a list, which I can't import into excel rows because of the fact that it's a list inside a list...

Comment: @MoofinTheExplorer you welcome, check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/apartment/for-sale/leuven/3000')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'xl-surface-ch'}):
    item = item.text.strip()
    if 'm²' in item:
        print(item[0:item.find('m')])
    else:
        item = 0
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
84 
70 
80 
32 
149 
22 
75 
30 
23 
104 
0
95 
129 
26 
55 
26 
25 
28 
33 
210 
37 
69 
36 
19 
119 
20 
20 
129 
154 
25
```

Comment: This is great! But it skips over the ones that don't have the sqm filled in. So it wouldn't align properly with the other data. Any ideas how to tackle that? Perhaps by adding an if not? I'll try that out right now.

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot! You're really helping me become a better programmer, faster.

Comment: Could you just explain this part to me?         (item[0:item.find('m')])  I don't quite get how this returns the result I'm looking for.

Comment: @MoofinTheExplorer it's start from the first of the string and end once it's find `m`